# How can I copy and paste an Excel worksheet to a new book without changing references?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy and paste a worksheet from one Excel workbook to another. The worksheet integrates into local models of that worksheet. Therefore, I need the cell references from the copied worksheet to remain the same in the absolute sense.

For example, a cell with `"='Sheet1'C1"` must remain `"='Sheet1'C1"` rather than `"='[OriginalWorkbook]Sheet1'C1"`

Right now I am getting the unintended consequence while using,

```
Sub TransferSheet(wka As Workbook, wkb As Workbook, WorksheetName As String)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    wka.Activate
    Set ws1 = wka.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    wkb.Activate
    ws1.Copy after:=wkb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Comment: You can easily change the source of data in your new file back to itself.

Comment: here is the code wkb.ChangeLink "c:\excel\wka.xls", 
 "c:\excel\wkb.xls", xlExcelLinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a [page](https://superuser.com/questions/397431/copy-excel-worksheet-and-maintain-relative-cell-reference-in-formulas) on Super User that gave me an idea of how to solve this in VBA. As this is a common problem, people have used many solutions such as copy and pasting content to a text editor and then back to the new sheet. Another solution is to use a Find and Replace function.

Adapting this to VBA the problem can be solved by conducting a find and replace on the sheets after they have been copied.

```
Sub TransferSheet(wka As Workbook, wkb As Workbook, WorksheetName As String)
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   wka.Activate
   Set ws1 = wka.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
   wkb.Activate
   ws1.Copy after:=wkb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
   wkb.ChangeLink "wka.xls", "wkb.xls", xlExcelLinks

   Dim sht As Worksheet
   Dim fnd As Variant
   Dim rplc As Variant

   fnd = "'[" & wka.Name & "]Summary'!"
   rplc = ""

   For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
   Next sht
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
Sub TransferSheet(wka As Workbook, wkb As Workbook, WorksheetName As String)
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    wka.Activate
    Set ws1 = wka.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
    wkb.Activate
    ws1.Copy after:=wkb.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    wkb.ChangeLink "wka.xls", "wkb.xls", xlExcelLinks
End Sub
```

Edit: This solution works to change the links on Macro buttons.